# MySql PDO and exceptions thrown within 2nd level internal procedure calls

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

We have a situation with the following...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS unit_throw_error;
CREATE PROCEDURE unit_throw_error() CALL throw_error();

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS throw_error;
CREATE PROCEDURE throw_error() CALL _proc_does_not_exist();
```

If you call the first procedure `unit_throw_error`, the php PDO object will not throw an exception as created through the 2nd procedure. Some sample code:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test";
$username = "...";
$password = "...";

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

$query = "CALL unit_throw_error();";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

do {
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} while ($stmt->nextRowset() && $stmt->columnCount());

$stmt->closeCursor();
```

The expected result is a thrown `PDOException` but this doesn't happen. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

We've isolated this to only happen when a successful select occurs before the line that throws an exception...

```
-- CREATE DATABASE `exception_test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

use exception_test;

DROP TABLE  if exists `test_data`;
CREATE TABLE `test_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `some_field` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test_data` (`some_field`) VALUES ('sdf');
INSERT INTO `test_data` (`some_field`) VALUES ('fgh');
INSERT INTO `test_data` (`some_field`) VALUES ('ghj');

drop procedure if exists `unit_throw_error`;
create procedure unit_throw_error() call unit_throw_error_2();

drop procedure if exists `unit_throw_error_2`;
delimiter //
create procedure unit_throw_error_2()
  begin

  select * from test_data;

  call unknown_procedure();

  end//
delimiter ;
```

Does anyone know why when a select query causes the exception to not be thrown?

Comment: I get an exception for both: `Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE test._proc_does_not_exist does not exist`

Comment: Also worth mentioning that for a one-line procedure you can skip `BEGIN` and `END` and the delimiter change. Make for much simpler MCVEs.

Comment: Thanks @miken32 for your comments. I've further isolated this and updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with stored procedures, [you need to call `next_result()`](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call) method, in order to make PDO aware of the other results returned by the procedure.

So, the code should be

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL unit_throw_error()");
$stmt->execute();
do {
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    var_dump($data);
} while ($stmt->nextRowset() && $stmt->columnCount());
```

In this case PDO will fetch the next result from a database, and if this result is an error, then exception will be thrown.

**Edit:**

It seems that for this particular case of *syntax* error (i.e. one that occurs even before the execution), you don't actually need to call `nextRowset()`. Instead, just make sure that PDO is set into `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

But nevertheless, `nextRowset()` have to be called with stored procedures anyway, in order to let other queries to be run and in order to get the error if several resultsets are expected.

So (just to prove my answer useful), if you change your code to this:

```
drop procedure if exists `unit_throw_error`;
create procedure unit_throw_error() call unit_throw_error_2();

drop procedure if exists `unit_throw_error_2`;
delimiter //
create procedure unit_throw_error_2()
  begin

  select * from test_data;
  select * from non_existent;

  end//
delimiter ;
```

and run PDO code without `nextRowset()` call, no error will appear. But with the code I posted above the error will be thrown,

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'exception_test.non_existent' doesn't exist

Comment: Unfortunately we have already tried this and it still did not get the error. I've updated the question with our sample code we are using.

Comment: I can see you have quite some experience in PDO, and its rather funny as I had found your article during my research on this issue. Good article btw!

Comment: I've rechecked this and your answer came out 100%. I'm a little shocked as we tried it all. I see though that at some point of our research we had set the ERRMODE_EXCEPTION to ERRMODE_SILENT.... HOWEVER, we re-tested this now with silent on, and $pdo->errorCode() does not report the error, where ERRMODE_EXCEPTION will through an exception.

Comment: Hm. With your code I've got `Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE exception_test.unknown_procedure does not exist'`. What PHP version?

Comment: PHP 5.6, but we've discovered now that error shows with only ERRMODE_EXCEPTION and not ERRMODE_SILENT even though calling  $pdo->errorCode().

Comment: Ah I see you got it already. Great. Yes, errorCode() sometimes fail and I dunno why. So I consider ERRMODE_EXCEPTION the only reliable error reporting mode